# eBay Sold Item Scrape Selenium Pagination

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I was able to scrape the first page of eBay sold items, so I attempted the pagination, here's what I have:

```
    ebay_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=oakley+sunglasses&_sacat=0&Brand=Oakley&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_ipg=200&_oaa=1&_fsrp=1&_dcat=79720'

    # Load in html
    html = requests.get(ebay_url)
    # print(html.text)

    driver = wd.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/mburley/Downloads/chromedriver')
    driver.maximize_window() #Maximizes window
    driver.implicitly_wait(30) # Gives an implicit wait for 30 seconds
    driver.get(ebay_url)


    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) # Makes driver wait 20 seconds
    sold_date = []
    title = []
    price = []
    i = 1

    ## Loop here to get multiple pages
    next_page = True
    while next_page: 
        try:
            # for item in all_items
            for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'title-- 
            tagblock')]/span[@class='POSITIVE']"):
                try:
                    # Get Sale Date of item and update 'data'
                    sold_date.append(item.text)
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    # Element not found
                    sold_date.append(None)
                try:
                    # Get title of each item and update 'data'
                    title.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath(f". 
                    (//div[contains(@class,'title--tagblock')]/span[@class='POSITIVE']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'tag')]/following-sibling::a/h3)[{i}]").text)
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    # Element not found
                    title.append(None)
                try:
                # Get price of each item and update 'data'
                price.append(item.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//div[contains(@class,'title--tagblock')]/span[@class='POSITIVE']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'tag')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'details')]/descendant::span[@class='POSITIVE'])[{i}]").text)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                # Element not found
                price.append(None)
            i = i + 1

            # Print results of scraped data on page
            print(sold_date)
            print(title)
            print(price)

            data = {
                'Sold_date': sold_date,
                'title': title,
                'price': price
                   } 
            # Load Next Page by clicking button
            button = driver.find_element_by_name('pagination__next icon-link')
            button.click()
            print("Clicked on Next Page!")
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            print("Done!")
            next_page = False

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv('out_two.csv', index = 0)
```

After I had the code to scrape page 1, I added:

```
    ... code ...
    ## Loop here to get multiple pages
    next_page = True
    while next_page: 
        try:
            ... code to scrape page 1 ...
            # Load Next Page by clicking button
            button = driver.find_element_by_name('pagination__next icon-link')
            button.click()
            print("Clicked on Next Page!")
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            print("Done!")
            next_page = False
```

Which unfortunately edits the code to scrape the first item, then searches for the next page, and can't find the "button" so it exits and prints done. I don't know a lot about scraping, so I tried to follow an online example. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: That link doesn't work for me (ebay resets); could be a geo location thing.  If I do a search on ebay and inspect the next page I see this: https://ibb.co/3Nym8H3.  Is it the same for you?

Comment: Hmm.. the link works for me, and the html is slightly different. The 2 filters are 'oakley' and 'sold items' and the page has been adjusted to 200 results. Any thoughts @cruisepandey?